# Encoded JS with hex numbers and "trash code"

Tags: javascript, encode

Is there any way to encode `JS` code that looks like this (part of the code):

```
    (function (_0x4d1e87, _0x3e9ba3) {
    function _0x109baf(_0x5c7e18, _0x188857, _0x573be6, _0x4629bc) {
        return _0x14fe(_0x5c7e18 - -0x2e5, _0x4629bc);
    }
    var _0x3efbf6 = _0x4d1e87();
    while (!![]) {
        try {
            var _0x51d81e = parseInt(_0x109baf(0x4dc, 0x409, 0xda, 0x772)) / (0x1742 + 0x23e0 + 0x1 * -0x3b21) + -parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(0x4f0, 0x5b0, 0x8d0, 0x517)) / (0x259b + 0x711 + -0x2caa * 0x1) + -parseInt(_0x109baf(0x37d, 0xa3, 0x7a3, 0x5f7)) / (-0xb8 * 0x1f + 0x197 * 0xa + 0x665) * (-parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(-0x1e4, -0xee, -0x38a, -0x4e)) / (-0xe0a + 0x2454 + -0x1646)) + -parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(0x915, 0x515, 0x98a, 0x584)) / (-0x53 * 0x46 + 0x18fb + -0x244) * (-parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(0x88d, 0x415, 0x503, 0x51b)) / (0x11b * -0x22 + -0x31 * -0x70 + -0x2e * -0x5a)) + -parseInt(_0x109baf(0x173, 0x14a, -0xdf, 0x12f)) / (-0x1795 + 0x1ca2 + -0x506) + parseInt(_0x109baf(0x260, -0xe7, 0x39b, 0x163)) / (-0x653 * 0x3 + -0x694 * -0x4 + -0x74f) + -parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(0x23c, 0xbb, 0xe4, 0xbd)) / (-0x80 + -0x1 * -0x22b8 + -0x222f) * (-parseInt(_0x3b5bbf(-0x29, -0x94, 0x106, -0x264)) / (0x43a * 0x4 + -0x47d + 0xc61 * -0x1));
            if (_0x51d81e === _0x3e9ba3) break;
            else _0x3efbf6['push'](_0x3efbf6['shift']());
        } catch (_0x36806b) {
            _0x3efbf6['push'](_0x3efbf6['shift']());
        }
    }
}(_0x4c86, -0x7ab89 + -0x164ce8 + 0xdf661 * 0x3));

function _0x14b713(_0x34c869, _0xa7f67d, _0x12dd66, _0x2aba0a) {
    return _0x14fe(_0xa7f67d - -0x181, _0x34c869);
}(function () {
    var _0x5dfaac = {
            'bEgta': function (_0x32a431, _0xfcb806) {
                return _0x32a431 === _0xfcb806;
            }
            , 'OrnVZ': _0x2b26b(0x1d9, -0x1d2, 0x45e, 0xc0)
            , 'UKDzG': 'deposit_cr' + _0x2b26b(0x42c, -0x21b, 0xff, 0x32)
            , 'AzAnz': _0x2d0e39(-0x33f, -0x194, 0xaf, 0x402) + _0x2d0e39(0x569, -0x3d, 0x334, -0x28)
            , 'HVifc': 'death'
            , 'oAjSO': 'intro'
            , 'fkiFj': _0x2b26b(0x445, 0x518, 0xd3, 0x423)
            , 'tdcYU': 'animations' + _0x2b26b(0x63, -0x94, -0x209, 0x1de)
            , 'mquMx': _0x2b26b(-0x87, 0x5e, -0x84, 0xc) + _0x2b26b(0x4ff, 0x704, 0x360, 0x2f9)
            , 'YAKDv': _0x2b26b(-0x12c, 0x223, 0x41, 0x211)
            , 'CtPsC': _0x2b26b(-0x179, -0x135, 0x6f, 0xc) + _0x2b26b(0x226, 0x586, 0xe0, 0x3d4) + 'g'
            , 'kVSTA': _0x2d0e39(0xb00, 0x4e1, 0x788, 0x76e)
            , 'LOphM': function (_0x420dda, _0x4103dd) {
                return _0x420dda !== _0x4103dd;
            }
```

The whole program contains 7000 lines of code. I suppose it has a lot of trash. (intentionally)

Comment: or you mean you need [JS obfuscation](https://obfuscator.io/)?

Comment: It doesnt really make the code readable, can i get original variable names?